# Speeding up DASK bag processing of a text file?

Tags: python, performance, dask, bag

Hi I have the following code :

```
import dask.bag as db 

class Similarity(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.bag = None

    @staticmethod
    def olap(item, ary) :
        iix,item = item.strip().split(':')
        aix,ary = ary.strip().split(':')
        o = len( set(item.split(' ')) & set(ary.split(' ')) )
        return o,int(aix),int(iix),item


    def process(self, file):
        self.bag = db.read_text(file)   
        rv = []
        for c, i in enumerate(self.bag.take(100)) :
            rv.append( self.bag.map(Similarity.olap, i).filter(lambda x: x[1] != x[2]).max().compute() )
        return rv
```

For now i'm processing ~10_000 line text file, which is a light load.
It is simply a Sentence per line which is split to words and compared.
Every line with ALL the other lines in the file.

The problem is that it is too SLOOOW ... 100 steps take ~1m 20sec with all the CPUs working.
At the same time the score function is fast ~2 micro secs

```
In [171]: %timeit Similarity.olap('5:aaa bbb ccc dddd  ooooooooo ppppppppppp jee', '7:bbb aa ccc ddd ee uu oooo pppp')                                                       
2.09 µs ± 56.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

So do you have any tricks to help me SPEED it up ?

Answer (score 1):

Comparing `10**4` lines to each other is `10**8` computations, so it's not a very light computation. If your similarity metric is symmetric (seems to be the case), then you can halve the time, by comparing only one of every pair (so similarity from A to B is sufficient to know similarity from B to A).

In terms of the actual code, you have `.compute` inside a loop, which will slow down computations because next iteration must wait for the previous computation to complete. Rough pseudocode for a faster way is as follows (will probably need adjusting for actual results):

```py
# ensure this is in the imports along with the dask bag
import dask


# other code including Class definition skipped

    def process(self, file):
        self.bag = db.read_text(file)   
        rv = []
        for c, i in enumerate(self.bag.take(100)) :
            # no compute inside the loop
            rv.append( self.bag.map(Similarity.olap, i).filter(lambda x: x[1] != x[2]).max())

        # now the rv contains lazy objects only, so compute them at once
        rv = dask.compute(rv)
        return rv
```

Comment: ooo i see ;) .. i already tried vaex which was faster ~15sec (need conv cvs => hdf5), then mmap-ed txt file which was comparable and finally mmaped file using Ray ... that thing is fast, 2-3 secs !!  ;)

Comment: It might be possible to get some speed up also by chunking tasks, see docs:

> The scheduler adds about one millisecond of overhead per task or Future object. While this may sound fast it’s quite slow if you run a billion tasks. If your functions run faster than 100ms or so then you might not see any speedup from using distributed computing.

[link](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/efficiency.html)